Non-top, compactly supported differential forms admit compactly supported primitives
I'm having problems solving question 2.c) of the following exercises:
Exercise 1. Let $\alpha=\sum_{i=1}^{m} \alpha(\mathbf{x}) d x^{i} \in \Omega^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$ with $d \alpha=0$.
a) Show that
$$
f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{m} x^{i} \int_{0}^{1} \alpha^{i}(u \mathbf{x}) d u
$$
defines a primitive of $\alpha$, that is $d f=\alpha$.
b) Show that if $\alpha$ has compact support and $m>1$, then it admits a primitive which is also of compact support.
c) Show that the previous item is false when $m=1$.
Exercise 2. Consider $\alpha \in \Omega^{k}\left(\mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$ given by
$$
\alpha=\frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}} \alpha_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}}(\mathbf{x}) d x^{i_{1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge d x^{i_{k}}
$$
where $\alpha_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}}(\mathbf{x}) \in C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$ that are skew-symmetric in the indices.
a) State explicitly under what condition on $\alpha_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}}(\mathbf{x})$ we have that $d \alpha=0$.
b) If $d \alpha=0$ show that $\alpha=d \beta$ where
$$
\beta=\frac{1}{(k-1)!} \sum_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}}\left(\int_{0}^{1} u^{k-1} \alpha_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}}(u \mathbf{x}) d u\right) x^{i_{1}} d x^{i_{2}} \wedge \cdots \wedge d x^{i_{k}}
$$
c) Show that if $m>k$ and $\alpha \in \Omega^{k}\left(\mathbb{R}^{m}\right)$ is closed and of compact support, then it admits a primitive which is also of compact support. Show that this need not be true if $k=m$.
Attempted solution:
1.a) and 2.a) are simply special cases of the Poincare lemma (another good proof can be found in Warner's "Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds"). A direct computation using the rules for exterior derivation proves the claim.
1.b) and 2.b) can be solved with direct calculation. Using coordinates and sticking to ordered indices, one gets:
\begin{aligned}\mathrm{d}\alpha & =\sum_{i_{0}<\dotsb<i_{k}}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(-1\right)^{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i_{j}}}\alpha_{{i_{0}}\dots i_{j-1}i_{j+1}\dots i_{k}}\right)\mathrm{d}x^{i_{0}}\wedge\dotsb\wedge\mathrm{d}x^{i_{k}} \end{aligned}
where the terms in parentheses vanishing is a necessary condition for the form to be closed.
1.c) was answered in this post. So the only part missing is 2.c), which I was told could be proven by contradiction using Stokes theorem and 1.c), but I still haven't been able to solve it.
Thanks in advance for any help.

You should edit the question it’s not clear what you are struggling with

Sorry, edited the typos in the last paragraph. Hope it's now clear.
